# I wrote a recursive method in java to calculate the height of a tree and my question is how can I get this method to print the height one time

Tags: java, recursion, printing, tree, height

So here is my method:

```
public int getHeight(IntTreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int height = 1 + Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right));
         
        System.out.println(height);
        }
        return height;
    }
```

I know that since it's a recursive method it will print the height in loops until it reaches the final height, but what I want is for this method to print the final height only. Any ideas on how to make this work anyone? thanks.

Comment: Put the output statement in the main program, not in the `getHeight()` method.

Comment: I can do that of course, but my assignment (data structure course) is to write a method that prints the height when it's called from main...

Comment: Then you have to write another method that invokes the recursive function and prints the result.

Comment: I thought about it too, but then it makes the code very complicated and not efficient. 
I thought to trace the path of the method and nest the System.out.print in an if/else statement, but it is so tedious to find the path for any given tree..
Maybe I need to write a method that uses a while loop instead of a recursive method but it will be much harder...

Comment: "makes the code very complicated and not efficient" - absolutely the contrary, using an additional method will make it much easier and efficient then having some additional kind of logic (if/else) in the recursive method || `public void printHeight(TreeNode root) { System.out.println(getHeight(root)); }` almost can't be less complicated

Comment: Alright, I'm convinced! This is not to much to add and it does the work.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a second method e. g. `printHeight` to print the height and use the `getHeight` method only to return the height.

E. g.:

```
public int getHeight(IntTreeNode root) {
    if(root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int height = 1 + Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right));
    return height;
}
public void printHeight() {
    System.out.println(getHeight());
}
```